# Node.js built-in distributed cache

Tags: node.js, database, caching, replication, leveldb

I'm looking for something for distributed cache for node.js. It should be:

- built-in (works inside node process)
- distributed and replicated between any number of servers (1 or 2 should be enough for concensus)
- consistency is not critical
- automatic peer discovery is preferably (e.g. by UDP)
- should have one lider in one period of time (who will periodically update the cache)

I tried to find something for LevelDB (memdown), but all project are not maintained for several years. Maybe they are so stable, but I'm not sure. It is also possible to take a discovery and consensus algorithm and implement other things manually, but I can't find js-implementaion of Raft etc. for 1+ peers.

Advise me something, please.

Answer (score 0):

I've chosen http://cote.js.org/ - mesh network. This is not full decision, just discovery and pub sub service. Plus lider choosing algorithm which I wrote manually.